# Simpleform + bootstrap: getting rid of the ellipsis and hover text for required fields

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, simple-form, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I recently upgraded simpleform and bootstrap, which I'm using together. My required fields now have ellipses underneath the asterisks, and when users hover, they get a tooltip.

How can I customize or remove that behavior?

Comment: Do you have an <abbr> or similar wrapping the asterisks?

Comment: Yes, there was something like that, and I just made the wrapper have `display: none`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made the wrapper class of the ellipses have `display: none`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just hide the abbr you lose the information about the field being required. What you need to do is style the abbr correctly, for example to get rid of the ellipsis do:

```
/** CUSTOMIZE SIMPLEFORM SHITTY STYLINGS **/
abbr[title='required'] {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```